# Post Request causes android.volley.NoConnectionError

Tags: android-studio, https, android-volley

I'm trying to send data from my android app to my .NET core Web API on localhost.

The following is the error I get:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

The following is the code for post request on Android Studio using volley.

```
 submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ManualHubActivity.this);

                // 2 Create a post request
                String url = "https://10.103.79.15:44371/continous/Add-Json";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        editValue.setText(s);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        editValue.setText("request was aborted" + volleyError);
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("UserID","205");
                        map.put("Value","205");
                        map.put("ReadtingType","205");


                        return map;
                    }
                };

                // 3 take post Request added to queue
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when your device's api is less than 19

try to add this function before your connection :

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```